# Enviar Currículo formatado com php

Tags: php, html

Estou criando um formulário para uma empresa para cadastro de currículo e já está funcionando, só que fiz para gerar o currículo e imprimir, alguém poderia me falar como seria feito para que, ao clicar em enviar, ele envie este arquivo para um determinado e-mail formatado já. O código que estou usando está logo abaixo.

```js
<?php
//Captura o modelo selecionado
$modelo = $_POST['modelo'];

//Verifica se o cliente selecionou uma foto no formulário ou deixou em branco
if($_FILES['foto']['size'] > 0){
    //Obtém o conteúdo da imagem (conteúdo binário)
    $conteudo = file_get_contents($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name']);
    
    //Obtém o tipo da imagem enviada (jpg, png)
    $tipo = pathinfo($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    
    //Gera a imagem em base64 para poder colocar na tag <img> do curriculo
    $foto = 'data:image/' . $tipo . ';base64,' . base64_encode($conteudo);
} else {
    //Se o cliente não selecionou uma foto, usamos a imagem padrão
    $foto = "img/avatar-1.png";
}

//Gera um array com os dados a serem enviados para impressão no currículo
//Cada elemento do array recebe o valor de um campo do formulário
$dados = array(
    'foto' => $foto,
    'nome' => $_POST['nome'],
    'cargo' => $_POST['cargo'],
    'endereco' => $_POST['endereco'],
    'telefone' => $_POST['telefone'],
    'email' => $_POST['email'],
    'resumo' => $_POST['resumo'],
    'formacoes' => isset($_POST['formacao-curso']) ?
                   array(
                        'cursos' => $_POST['formacao-curso'],
                        'instituicoes' => $_POST['formacao-instituicao'],
                        'conclusoes' => $_POST['formacao-conclusao']
                    ) : null, //Se o usuário não adicionou nenhuma formação, esse elemento ficará nulo
    'experiencias' => isset($_POST['experiencia-cargo']) ? 
                      array(
                        'cargos' => $_POST['experiencia-cargo'],
                        'empresas' => $_POST['experiencia-empresa'],
                        'inicios' =>  $_POST['experiencia-inicio'],
                        'fins' =>  $_POST['experiencia-fim'],
                      ) : null //Se o usuário não adicionou nenhuma experiência, esse elemento ficará nulo
);

//Carrega o arquivo referente ao modelo de currículo selecionado
//Quando faz isso, poderemos imprimir o conteúdo da variável $dados no currículo
require_once("modelos/{$modelo}.php");
```

Comment: Samuel, você pode usar o [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). Olhe as documentação deles que lá tem um passo a passo bem explicado.

Comment: vou dar uma olhada, obrigado

Comment: Qualquer coisa me chama que eu tenho uma estrutura bem definida que eu uso para o PHPMailer.

Comment: rapaz, estou acustumado a enviar tados simples com php, mas não estou entendendo muito com phpmailer, se quiser me da uma luz ai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para enviar e-mail com anexo, no seu caso um pdf, você pode utilizar a classe *PHPMailer*, que nada mais é do que uma classe, ou melhor, biblioteca, que permite o envio de e-mails via conexão *SMTP* ou *POP3*.

Antes de começar siga o tutorial abaixo:

1. Baixe a última versão (nesse caso é 6.0.5) do [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).
2. Descompacte o arquivo baixado e mantenha somente esses arquivos junto com a pasta `src`:

   - Exception.php, OAuth.php, PHPMailer.php, POP3.php e SMTP.php;

Agora vamos ao que realmente interessa, o envio de e-mail.

Vamos definir uma estrutura básica ao nosso projeto.

```
/seu_projeto/
   |--app/
   |    |--class/
   |    |       |--PHPMailer/
   |    |       |            |--src/
   |    |       |            |     |Exception.php
   |    |       |            |     |OAuth.php
   |    |       |            |     |PHPMailer.php
   |    |       |            |     |POP3.php
   |    |       |            |     |SMTP.php
   |    |Mail.php
```

Com isso já podemos realizar o script de envio de e-mail utilizando a classe `Mail.php`. No exemplo para um formulário de contato, mas que envia um anexo.

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

class Mail
{
    public function sendMail($name, $email, $phone, $subject, $message)
    {
        require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
        require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
        require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';

        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        try {
            // Server settings
            $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Define o mail para usar o SMTP
            $mail->Host = 'smtp.dominio.net';                     // Define o host do e-mail
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Permite autenticação SMTP 
            $mail->Username = 'exemplo@dominio.net';              // Conta de e-mail que enviará o e-mail
            $mail->Password = 'exemplo123';                       // Senha da conta de e-mail
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Permite encriptação TLS
            $mail->Port = 587;                                    // Porta TCP que irá se conectar
            $mail->SMTPOptions = array( // Configuração adicional, não obrigatória (caso de erro de ssl)
                'ssl' => array(
                    'verify_peer' => false,
                    'verify_peer_name' => false,
                    'allow_self_signed' => true
                )
            );

            // Recipients
            $mail->setFrom('seuemail@gmail.com', 'Título do e-mail, ou assunto'); // Define o remetente
            $mail->addAddress('aleatoria@gmail.com', 'Contato Site');             // Define o destinário

            $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');                         // Adicona anexos (só passar o arquivo, localização dele)

            // Content
            $mail->isHTML(true); // Define o formato do e-mail para HTML
            $mail->Subject = 'Contato feito pelo site';
            $mail->Body = "
                        <html>
                        <head>
                        </head>
                        <body>
                        <h2>Coloque aqui o seu assunto</h2>

                        <table>
                          <tr>
                            <th>Nome</th>
                            <th>E-mail</th>
                            <th>Telefone</th>
                            <th>Assunto</th>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>$name</td>
                            <td>$email</td>  
                            <td>$phone</td>
                            <td>$subject</td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>

                        <h2>Conteúdo da mensagem</h2>

                        <p>$message</p>

                        </body>
                        </html>";
            $mail->send(); // Envia o e-mail
            return true;
        } catch (Exception $e) { // Se capturar exceção retorna false
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

[Documentação do PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

[Fórum do PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues)

Comment: Entendi o quer fazer, mas com 42 campos vai dar certo?

Comment: 42 campos de que?

Comment: Opa esse é outro assunto, vou substituir o código e vou testar

Comment: Se funcionar lembre de dar um voto positivo a resposta e marcar como a correta :)

Comment: Clicando em enviar só aparace uma tela em branco

Comment: Aciona o debug: `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;` e vê se ele mostra algum erro - coloca logo no começo

Comment: em branco ainda

Comment: Como está a sua estrutura do projeto?

Comment: index          
geraCurriculo  -> src -> Exception
    OAuth
               PHPMailer

Comment: A classe Mail.php você deve deixar dentro da pasta geraCurriculo, e lembre de colocar src dentro de uma outra pasta chamada PHPMailer. Outra pergunta, você alterou o valor de host, username, password né?

Comment: nada ainda, mudei o diretório do src e nada, vou ter que fazer de outro jeito mesmo. agradeço ai